# Lucene not finding expected data

Tags: search, lucene

I'm having an issue with Lucene and I'm hoping someone can give me an idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using lucene 4.4 and I'm using the StandardAnalyser. I'm trying to do a search on one field but I'm getting a weird result.

For example when I search the word "gros*" the result return records with "grossesse". This is fine and as expected. But when I search with "gross*" it finds nothing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is there a setting I'm missing?
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

**This is my Index**

```
private void createIndex(Analyzer analyzer, String catalogueId, Locale locale, Directory index) throws IOException {

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer); 
    IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config); 
    Document doc = null;

    for (ProduitCatalogue produitCatalogue : produitCataloguesMap.get(catalogueId + locale.getLanguage()).values()) {
        doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new IntField("id", produitCatalogue.getId(), Store.YES));
        TextField desc = new TextField("description", produitCatalogue.getDescription(), Store.YES);
        doc.add(desc);
        w.addDocument(doc);
    }

    w.close();
    }
}
```

**This my createQuery**

```
private Query createQuery(String searchTxt, Analyzer analyzer) throws ParseException {

    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, "description", analyzer);
    queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
    queryParser.setAutoGeneratePhraseQueries(false);    
    Query q = queryParser.parse(searchTxt);

    return q;
}
```

**This is my Analyzer**

```
Analyzer analyzer = englishAnalyzer;

if (Locale.CANADA_FRENCH.getLanguage().equals(locale.getLanguage())) {
    analyzer = frenchAnalyzer;
}

Query q = createQuery(searchTxt, analyzer);
DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexMap.get(catalogueId + locale.getLanguage()));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(HITS_PER_PAGE, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefix queries (as well as Wildcard, Fuzzy and Regex queries) are not passed through the analyzer.  Since you are using language-specific analyzers (`EnglishAnalyzer` and `FrenchAnalyzer`), the indexed data passed through the Analyzer will be stemmed.  I would guess, that after stemming, "grossesse" is indexed as the stem "gros".  Searching for "gross" without the wildcards would, I presume, get a hit (I haven't gone over the pertinent stemming logic to say that with absolute certainty though).

One possible way to allow both stemming and wildcard querying, would be to index the data in two fields, one stemmed using the language analyzers, the other unstemmed, using `StandardAnalyzer`.  You could either, always search both, or search selectively based on what is in your query.  For user entered queries particularly, searching both fields simultaneously would be the right approach to my mind.